# Why are RESTful Applications easier to scale

Tags: web-services, rest, architecture

I always read that one reason to chose a RESTful architecture is (among others) better scalability for Webapplications with a high load.

Why is that? One reason I can think of is that because of the defined resources which are the same for every client, caching is made easier. After the first request, subsequent requests are served from a memcached instance which also scales well horizontally.

But couldn't you also accomplish this with a traditional approach where actions are encoded in the url, e.g. (booking.php/userid=123&travelid=456&foobar=789).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A part of REST is indeed the URL part (it's the R in REST) but the S is more important for scaling: state.

The server end of REST is stateless, which means that the server doesn't have to store anything across requests. This means that there doesn't have to be (much) communication between servers, making it *horizontally scalable*.

Of course, there's a small bonus in the R (representational) in that a *load balancer* can easily route the request to the right server if you have nice URLs, and GET could go to a slave while POSTs go to masters.

Answer (score 4):

I think what Tom said is very accurate, however another problem with scalability is the barrier to change upon scaling. So, one of the biggest tenants of REST as it was intended is HyperMedia. Basically, the server will own the paths and pass them to the client at runtime. This allows you to change your code without breaking existing clients. However, you will find most implementations of REST to simply be RPC hiding behind the guise of REST...which is not scalable.

Answer (score 3):

"Scalable" or ["web scale"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2F-DItXtZs) is one of the most abused terms when it comes to the web, the cloud and REST, and mainly used to convince management to get their support for moving their development team on board the REST train.

It is a buzzword that holds no value. If you search the web for "REST scalability" you'll find a lot of people parroting each other without any concrete evidence.

A REST service is exactly equally scalable as a service exposed over a SOAP interface. Both are just HTTP interfaces to an application service. How well this service actually scales depends **entirely** on how this service was actually implemented. It's possible to write a service that cannot scale as all in both REST and SOAP.

Yes, you can do things with SOAP that makes it scale worse, like rely on state and sessions. SOAP out of the box does not do this. This requires you to use a smarter load balancer, which you want anyway if you're really concerned with whatever form of scaling.

One thing that REST allows that SOAP doesn't, and that some other answers here address, is caching cacheable responses through an HTTP caching proxy or at the client side. This *may* make a REST service somewhat more lightly loaded than a SOAP service when a lot of operations' responses are cacheable. All this means is that fewer requests end up in your service.

Answer (score 2):

**A** reason (perhaps not **the** reason) is that RESTful services are sessionless.  This means you can easily use a load balancer to direct requests to various web servers without having to replicate session state among all of your web servers or making sure all requests from a single session go to the same web server.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason behind saying a rest application  is scalable is, Its built upon a HTTP protocol. Because HTTP is stateless. Stateless means it wont share anything between other request. So any request can go to any Server in a load balanced cluster. There is nothing forcing this user request go to this server. We can overcome this by using token.

Because of this statelessness,All REST application are very easy to scale. But if you want get high throughput(number of request capable in one second) in each server, then you should optimize blocking things  from the application. Follow the following tips

- Make each REST resource is a small entity. Don't read data from join of many tables.
- Read data from near by databases
- Use caches (Redis) instead of databases(You can save DISK I/O)
- Always keep data sources as much as near by because these blocks will make server resources (CPU) ideal and it no other request can use that resource while it is ideal.