# Why does scaling RESTful services is easier than SOAPful or other webservices?

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, soap, horizontal-scaling

In an interview, I was asked this question.

According to me, both are actually exposing a service.

If it takes `n` amount of time to scale a .net solution which implements a SOAPful service then shouldn't it take the same `n` amount of time to scale a .net solution which implements RESTful service?

Comment: I took the liberty of removing your secondary question. Please ask one question at a time and show your research. Read [ask].

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297471/why-are-restful-applications-easier-to-scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: S in REST stands for stateless, but you can make REST just as hard to scale as SOAP.

In time, I think your question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297471/why-are-restful-applications-easier-to-scale). Have you searched before posting?

Comment: Good on finding the duplicate. I posted my answer in the other question. Please flag this question as a duplicate of that one. :-)